# Scroll View Understanding

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiscrollview

I have a question on writing scrollviews. I have a scrollview and i need to change an image and a label in this scrollView everytime the user scrols. However i dont need to change the background or any thing else in this view. So is it possible to simply change the imageview image and label text when user scrolls?

I have currently written this but then this always displays the second image. I want to display different images when the view scrolls however keep the other aspects the same. Do i have to have multiple views for this?

```
 if (self.pageControl.currentPage = 1)
    [self.minkyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_1.png"]];  
 if (self.pageControl.currentPage = 2)
    [self.minkyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Shape1.png"]];
```

URGENT Thanks. I read from the apple doc that the best way is to have three views and keep changing. However i dont know how i would do that too. Without knowing how to change images.

Comment: For a start you've got `currentPage = 1` rather than `currentPage == 1`. But can you show us how you're creating the scroll view please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mattjgalloway suggests, you are actually assigning the currentPage values rather than comparing.  This is what your code ultimately boils down to:

- Assign currentPage to 1 (this will always evaluate to true)
- Show monkey_1.png
- Now, assign currentPage to 2 (this will always evaluate to true)
- Show Shape1.png

So, you see, you will always see Shape1.png.  Change your code to this:

```
switch (self.pageControl.currentPage)
{
   case 1:
      [self.minkyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_1.png"]]; 
      break;
   case 2:
      [self.minkyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Shape1.png"]];
      break;
   default:
      break;
}
```

Comment: Thank You that should work however my program doesnt even go into the scrollViewDidScroll method. Would you know why?

Comment: Did you assign the UIScrollView delegate?   `myScrollView.delegate = self`

Comment: Yes i did that and it goes into the method. However I have another problem now. on Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687029/scroll-viiew-class-ios/9687101#comment12308566_9687101 If you would know let me know. thanks