# Scroll VIiew Class iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiscrollview

My program doesnt even go into the `scrollViewDidScroll` method. I have no idea why. My view did load looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // Set the size of the content to be displayed
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * ScrollViewControllerNumberOfPages, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);

   // Turn on paging in the scroll view (can also be done in Interface Builder)
   self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

   NSLog(@"CurrentPage ViewDidLoad%@",self.pageControl.currentPage);
   switch (self.pageControl.currentPage)
   {
       case 1:
           [self.minkyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_1.png"]]; 
           NSLog(@"case1");
           break;
       case 2:
           [self.minkyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Shape1.png"]];
            NSLog(@"case2");
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }     
}
```

Also i have implemented the `scrollviewDelegate` on my interface like this. I don't see what i am doing wrong. It doesn't even go into the method called `scrollViewDidScroll`.

```
@interface MinkyScreenSwapViewController: UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGFloat contentWidth = scrollView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat halfContentWidth = contentWidth / 2;
NSInteger currentPage = (scrollView.contentOffset.x + halfContentWidth) / contentWidth;
self.pageControl.currentPage = currentPage;
NSLog(@"CurrentPage");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i did and that goes into the method now thank you. HOwever for self.pageControl.currentPage it always prints null.. Code edited above. Im not sure why this is.

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes

```
scrollView.delegate = self;

scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

If you are adding scroll view over image view, you have to explicitly set

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

For more convenience set

```
[[scrollView superView] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

These will make your scrollView delegate method active.